# What is the meaning for this CRON Expression

Tags: quartz-scheduler, cronexpression, crontrigger

0 * * /5 * ?

I want to execute a job with an interval of five days for once daily.I'll give my starting date and ending date as startAt() and endAt() will it gives me correct scheduling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron expression for running a job once in 5 days is

```
   0 0 */5 * *
```

Comment: i have a job and i'll give the start time as 10:30 AM then the job has to execute only at start time with an interval of five days

Comment: nikhil can u please help me in this,like i need to execute a job for every two mins from 24 between hours of 12-13 recursively for every two days will this CRON expression works for me ?   CRON -> 0 24/2 12-13 /2 * ?